# Remove XML Node when Freemarker Variable defined inside that node is not used or set

Tags: java, xml, xpath, freemarker

My XML has Freemarker Variables ${xyz} defined in it as show in the below example. After processing this XML against a Map I replaced Freemarker Variables with relevant values.

I would like to delete those XML nodes whose freemarker variables are not used.

Example Scenario:
Below XML having Freemarker variables ${xyz}. I also have empty nodes in them example ShouldNotDelete node.

Freemarker Template:

```
<property>
   <Address>
        <Organisation>${Organisation?c}</Organisation>
        <BuildingName>${BuildingName?c}</BuildingName>              
        <Town>${Town?c}</Town>
        <PostCode>${PostCode?c}</PostCode>
  </Address>
  <ShouldNotDelete></ShouldNotDelete>
</property>
```

I have a Map

```
Map { “Organisation” : “abc” ,  “PostCode” : “ME165AB” }
```

Both Town and Building Name are missing in this Map.

After processing Map and putting relevant values into above XML I get the below Result XML:

Result XML:

```
<property>
   <Address>
        <Organisation>abc</Organisation>
        <BuildingName></BuildingName>               
        <Town></Town>
        <PostCode>ME165AB</PostCode>
  </Address>
  <ShouldNotDelete></ShouldNotDelete>
</property>
```

I would like the unused freemarker nodes to be deleted. In the above case Town and BuildingName nodes should be deleted. Hence the Ideal output needed is below:

Ideal Result Output needed:

```
<property>
   <Address>
        <Organisation>abc</Organisation>
        <PostCode>ME165AB</PostCode>
  </Address>
  <ShouldNotDelete></ShouldNotDelete>
</property>
```

Could anyone please suggest an ideal answer either by using Freemarker template language (like using <#if > <#else> before nodes) or by using Java logic.

Comment: Put those elements into `#if`... but something isn't right here. If, for example, `Town` is missing from the `Map`, then FreeMarker should not print `<Town></Town>`, but should stop with error (undefined variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
<property>
   <Address>
         <#if Organisation??>
             <Organisation>${Organisation?c}</Organisation>
         </#if>         
  </Address>
  <ShouldNotDelete></ShouldNotDelete>
</property>
```